# How to apply strokeColor to cardView when selected

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

I want to know how can I apply stroke color to card view onClick and also deselect it when clicked again

Also, I have multiple card views, so if one is already selected and the stroke color is applied but if the user clicks another card view the stroke color disappeared from the first and is applied to the respected card view

How can I achieve this?

Right now I have applied a stroke color to one card view

Just as a note further, I want to get the selected `CardView` id or the amount when the donate button is clicked and pass the card view (amount) to the payment gateway.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

**donate_fragment.xml** // only the card view section and the button

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/select_an_amount"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:strokeColor="@color/wallet_holo_blue_light"
            app:strokeWidth="3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Card_Elevation_Color"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/_0_5"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Card_Elevation_Color"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/_1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Card_Elevation_Color"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/_5"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Card_Elevation_Color"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/_10"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Card_Elevation_Color"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/_50"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Card_Elevation_Color"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/_100"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal" />
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/donateBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
        android:text="@string/donate"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:cornerRadius="10dp" />
```

After Implementing the answer this is the result // Thank you @Zain

[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uLo6iRVisDVQ28Z0noWzpcBJ1f1XBAsy/view?usp=sharing)

**Update** // how to pass and get the selected cardView from the fragment into acitivity

**Donate_Fragment**

```
// Donate Btn  // navigating to the Activity

    donateBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.donateBtn);
    donateBtn.setOnClickListener(view12 -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), donate_final_activity.class);
        if (cardView1.isChecked()) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (cardView2.isChecked()) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (cardView3.isChecked()) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (cardView4.isChecked()) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (cardView5.isChecked()) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (cardView6.isChecked()) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }


    });
```

**donate_activity.java** // this is the activity i want to get the selected cardViews from the fragment

```
public class donate_final_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MaterialButton donateBtn;
    TextView selectedAmt;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.final_donate_activity);
        // just trying to get something from the fragment  but didnt understand how to do it
        Donate_Fragment donate_fragment = new Donate_Fragment();
        donate_fragment.getView();
       // end of trying haha ha

        selectedAmt = findViewById(R.id.selectedAmt); // also i want to set the text after getting the cardView for eg if cardView6 was seleceted i want to setText to 100 $

        //Donate btn // this the final button when the payment gateway will open
        donateBtn = findViewById(R.id.donateBtn_final);
        donateBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (cardView1.isChecked()){  // ofcourse this is not working as i didn't get the selected carView (or i say the listener) , i just keep it so you can get a understanding of what im trying to achive
                makePayment1();
            }
            if (cardView2.isChecked()) {
                makePayment2();
            }
            if (cardView3.isChecked()) {
                makePayment3();
            }
            if (cardView4.isChecked()) {
                makePayment4();
            }
            if (cardView5.isChecked()) {
                makePayment5();
            }
            if (cardView6.isChecked()) {
                makePayment6();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a selector for the stroke color to change for the `state_checked`:

selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#36B3E0" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Apply that to the `CardView`:

```
app:checkedIcon="@null"
app:strokeColor="@drawable/selector"
android:checkable="true"
```

`checkedIcon` is set to have not tick icon for the checked card.

Then change the check status in `OnClickListener`

But precede that by clearing all the checked cards using their surrounding `ViewGroup`, here's an extension function for that:

```
fun ViewGroup.clearCardSelection() {
    this.children.forEach {
        if (it is MaterialCardView)
            it.isChecked = false
    }
}
```

And the listener:

```
val listener = View.OnClickListener {
    if (it is MaterialCardView) {
        val isChecked = it.isChecked
        linearlayout1.clearCardSelection() // top LinearLayout
        linearlayout2.clearCardSelection() // bottom LinearLayout
        it.isChecked = !isChecked
    }
}
cardView.setOnClickListener(listener) // repeat this for the 6 cards
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Make sure to save the checked card state permanently to avoid losing it during configuration changes.

### UPDATE

Here is the java equivalent:

```
private void clearCardSelection(LinearLayout layout) {
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof MaterialCardView)
            ((MaterialCardView) child).setChecked(false);
    }
}


View.OnClickListener listener = view -> {
    if (view instanceof MaterialCardView) {
        MaterialCardView card = (MaterialCardView) view;
        boolean isChecked = card.isChecked();
        clearCardSelection(linearlayout1);
        clearCardSelection(linearlayout2);
        card.setChecked(!isChecked);
    }
};

cardView.setOnClickListener(listener); // repeat for all the cards
```

When I tested that in java; I got NPE on the `MaterialCaredView` layout, that was because of setting `app:checkedIcon="@null"` to null, to fix this, replace `app:checkedIcon="@null"` with `app:checkedIcon="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: ok sorry I only  added the checkeable=true to the first card view, now I have added it to all, and its working fine thank u so much brother

Comment: hey can you tell me how can I get the selected card view for the payment gateway (i only know how to do it with single one click but not with this)

Comment: Maybe You can use cardview id to differentiate between them

Comment: ok so how do i get selected carview when the donate button is click can i use that listener , please it would be very helpfull

Comment: Hey, there is a small issue, sorry I didn't check it before but the payment gateway I'm using was not allowing me to use the payment in a fragment and I have to use activity instead, I changed to activity but I don't understand how can I deal with the listener and the clearCardSelection method, please can you help with that to change it for activity

Comment: @VasantRaval Sounds like a different issue than mentioned in the question. We can't understand the behavior in both fragments & activity unless you share that, anyways I am welcome to check if you want to open a new question, good luck in it!

Comment: Hello, I've made some additions. Rather than convert the fragment into an activity, I created a new activity. After pressing the button after selecting the cardView, I would like to know which cardView was selected and start the makePayment method accordingly. From the fragment in the activity, how do I get the selectedCardview?

Comment: Hey @VasantRaval If you're using an activity, and host the card layout in a fragment; you can create a listener that is implemented by the activity; pass it to the fragment; and trigger its callback whenever you select a CardView or the Submit button. It's much easier than creating two activities (you can not use a listener in this case as the first activity is destroyed when you go to the second one)

Comment: ok i explain in detail , the issue is with the payment gateway it is not allowing me to start the paymentgateway when pay button is in a fragment , now as the donation fragment is a part of a bottom nav if i change the donation fragment into activity, i cant implement one activity with 3 fragments in a single bottom nav (as per the answers on SO on my question) and neither i want to change all the 3 raming fragment into an acitivity just for this single issue

Comment: so what im trying to do is when the user slected a amount(cardView) and click the donateBtn (now a right arrow which will navigate to the activity) i will start an activity which finaly have a last btn when pressed it opens the payment gateay and as obviously the selectd cardview was in the fragment not in the current activity i want to get that selected cardview so i can start the related makePayment method and also setText by getting the selected cardview and than setting the text

Comment: this is what im trying to do , but if you have a better solution to it please mention it , it wil be very helpfull

Comment: What is the hierarchy of your fragment.. As far as i got it is.. Activity_fragment_bottomnav_fragment

Comment: ok , i have the main activity with a fragment container and bottom nav only no other views  , now  i have only 4 main fragments and nothing else (except now ) the main 4 fragments which are the part of the bottom nav is Home (also the default one ), Guide, Donate and About ,now only the Donate fragment has a acitivity which just created for this particular issue, intotal i have one main activity and 4 main fragmensts (if we dont include the recent acitiviy i just created for this issue ) , this probably what youre asking for

Comment: here is a SR of it https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VYccb74UyYgd9MzUiBZJfRjnmQddcnuO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242657/discussion-between-zain-and-vasant-raval).

Comment: @VasantRaval HYG please check [here](https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/d/11e-SLBi_QYOVa3-gxX9o_QjlfzTyQqZAP9nRNR3GqR0/mobilebasic) you can pass the donation value as a double to the activity and retrieve it with `getIntent()`

Comment: hey brother thank you so much for the help it actually worked the page is opening, but as you have seen i have multiple makePayment() methods for all the diffrent amount, how can i add a if statement or a switch case in onClick , i make it work with the .isChecked in the fragmet previously , but what can i do here there is isChecled

Comment: @VasantRaval You can send another integer/String using `intent.putExtra` that has a unique value for each card, and check it like at the destination like we did with the donation double value

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved the second problem like this  and it worked

ok I know this is a very bad way to implement if(), please but if you any better solution please update this answer

```
// Donate Btn
        donateBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.donateBtn);
        donateBtn.setOnClickListener(view12 -> {
            if (cardView1.isChecked()) {
                makePayment1();
            }
            if (cardView2.isChecked()) {
                makePayment2();
            }
            if (cardView3.isChecked()) {
                makePayment3();
            }
            if (cardView4.isChecked()) {
                makePayment4();
            }
            if (cardView5.isChecked()) {
                makePayment5();
            }
            if (cardView6.isChecked()) {
                makePayment6();
            }
        });
```